# Function to search associative array keys

Tags: php

I am writing a shopping cart session handler class and I find myself repeating this certain chunk of code which searches a multidimensional associative array for a value match.

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $k => $v){

    if($v['productID'] == $productID){
        $key = $k;
        $this->found = true;
    }
}
```

I am repeating this when trying to match different values in the array.
Would there be an easy to to create a method whereby I pass the key to search and the value. (Sounds simple now I read that back but for some reason have had no luck)

Comment: instead of hardcoding strings just pass variables for whichever key you're looking for.

Comment: Literally just findKey($key['SOME_KEY'], $SOME_VALUE) ?
No idea why I can't get my head around this simple concept :-S

Comment: should be, except instead of `'some_key'`, do `$some_key` (I think $, haven't done php in a while, though) so you're using a var instead of the string "some_key"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
function findKey(array $array, $wantedKey, $match) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value){
        if ($value[$wantedKey] == $match) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$key = findKey($_SESSION['cart'], 'productID', $productID);

if ($key === null) {
    // no match in the cart
} else {
    // there was a match
}
```